# Optimizing tree branch data aggregation in SQL Server 2008 (recursion)

Tags: sql-server-2008, recursion, tree

I have a table containing stages and sub-stages of certain projects, and a table with specific tasks and estimated costs.
I need some way to aggregate each level (stages/sub-stages), to see how much it costs, but to do it at a minimum performance cost.

To illustrate this, I will use the following data structure:

```
CREATE TABLE stage
(
    id int not null,
    fk_parent int
)

CREATE TABLE task
(
    id int not null,
    fk_stage int not null,
    cost decimal(18,2) not null default 0
)
```

with the following data:

```
==stage==
id  fk_parent
1   null
2   1
3   1

==task==
id  fk_stage  cost
1   2         100
1   2         200
1   3         600
```

I want to obtain a table containing the total costs on each branch. Something like this:

```
Stage ID      Total Cost
1             900
2             300
3             600
```

But, I also want it to be productive. I don't want to end up with extremely bad solutions like [The worst algorithm in the world](http://bosker.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/the-worst-algorithm-in-the-world/). I mean this is the case. In case I'll request the data for all the items in the `stage` table, with the total costs, each total cost will be evaluated `D` times, where `D` is the depth in the tree (level) at which it is situated. I am afraid I'll hit extremely low performances at large amounts of data with a lot of levels.

SO,

I decided to do something which made me ask this question here.
I decided to add 2 more columns to the `stage` table, for caching.

```
...
calculated_cost decimal(18,2),
date_calculated_cost datetime
...
```

So what I wanted to do is pass another variable within the code, a `datetime` value which equals to the time when this process was started (pretty much unique). That way, if the `stage` row already has a `date_calculated_cost` which equals to the one I'm carrying, I don't bother calculating it again, and just return the `calculated_cost` value.

I couldn't do it with Functions (updates are needed to the `stage` table, once costs are calculated)
I couldn't do it with Procedures (recursion within running cursors is a no-go)
I am not sure temporary tables are suitable because it wouldn't allow concurrent requests to the same procedure (which are least likely, but anyway I want to do it the right way)
I couldn't figure out other ways.

I am not expecting a definite answer to my question, but I will reward any good idea, and the best will be chosen as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. A way to query the tables to get the aggregated cost.**

1. Calculate the cost for each stage.
2. Use a recursive CTE to get the level for each stage.
3. Store the result in a temp table.
4. Add a couple of indexes to the temp table.
5. Update the cost in the temp table in a loop for each level

The first three steps is combined to one statement. It might be good for performance to do the first calculation, `cteCost`, to a temp table of it's own and use that temp table in the recursive `cteLevel`.

```
;with cteCost as
(
  select s.id,
         s.fk_parent,
         isnull(sum(t.cost), 0) as cost
  from stage as s
    left outer join task as t
      on s.id = t.fk_stage
  group by s.id, s.fk_parent
),
cteLevel as
(
  select cc.id,
         cc.fk_parent,
         cc.cost,
         1 as lvl
  from cteCost as cc
  where cc.fk_parent is null
  union all
  select cc.id,
         cc.fk_parent,
         cc.cost,
         lvl+1
  from cteCost as cc
    inner join cteLevel as cl
      on cc.fk_parent = cl.id       
)
select *
into #task
from cteLevel

create clustered index IX_id on #task (id)
create index IX_lvl on #task (lvl, fk_parent)

declare @lvl  int
select @lvl = max(lvl)
from #task

while @lvl > 0
begin

  update T1 set
    T1.cost = T1.cost + T2.cost
  from #task as T1
    inner join (select fk_parent, sum(cost) as cost
                from #task
                where lvl = @lvl
                group by fk_parent) as T2
      on T1.id = T2.fk_parent

  set @lvl = @lvl - 1
end

select id as [Stage ID],
       cost as [Total Cost] 
from #task

drop table #task
```

**2. A trigger on table `task` that maintains a `calculated_cost` field in `stage`.**

```
create trigger tr_task 
on task 
after insert, update, delete
as
  -- Table to hold the updates
  declare @T table
  (
    id int not null, 
    cost decimal(18,2) not null default 0
  )

  -- Get the updates from inserted and deleted tables
  insert into @T (id, cost)
  select fk_stage, sum(cost)
  from (
          select fk_stage, cost
          from inserted
          union all
          select fk_stage, -cost
          from deleted
       ) as T   
  group by fk_stage

  declare @id int
  select @id = min(id)
  from @T

  -- For each updated row
  while @id is not null
  begin

    -- Recursive update of stage
    with cte as 
    (
      select s.id,
             s.fk_parent
      from stage as s
      where id = @id
      union all
      select s.id,
             s.fk_parent
      from stage as s
        inner join cte as c
          on s.id = c.fk_parent    
    )
    update s set
      calculated_cost = s.calculated_cost + t.cost 
    from stage as s
      inner join cte as c
        on s.id = c.id
      cross apply (select cost
                   from @T
                   where id = @id) as t   

    -- Get the next id
    select @id = min(id)
    from @T
    where id > @id
  end
```

Comment: While waiting for answers, I did solve my problem (I think). I added a few fields, I calculate the `level` of the stage inside a trigger, then run a cursor against all stages, ordered descending by the level, and obtain desired results. All is done inside a transaction which locks all resources, so no leaf in the tree could be modified. It seems to be working, but I need to end the integration part, to get some real data and test it, then I'll post it here too. Your answers seem to be correct, and very interesting to me. Thank you very much for your time.